# Unchecked cast warning when casting from MyAbstractParameter to T

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

sorry I know similar questions have been asked before, but none of them solve my current problem.

I currently have something like this:

```
abstract class MyAbstractParameter{ /* Some methods/parameters */ }

class MyParameter extends MyAbstractParameter { /*more methods/parameters*/ }

abstract class MyAbstractClass<T extends MyAbstractParameter> extends Thread{
    private List<MyAbstractParameter> list;
    public MyAbstractClass(List<MyAbstractParameter> list) { this.list = list; }
    public List<MyAbstractParameter> getList() { return list; }

    public void run() {
        for(MyAbstractParameter e : list) {
             doStuffWithList((T) e); // WARNING IS HERE WHEN CASTING! ! !!
        }
    }
    public abstract void doStuff(T element);
}

class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass<MyParameter> {
    public MyClass(List<MyAbstractParameter> list) { super(list); }
    public void doStuff(MyParameter element) { /* does something */ }
}
```

I want  that the method `getList()` to always returns a `List<MyAbstractParameter>`, and it does, however it gives me this warning, and I understand that the reason behind it is that if I send a list of `MyOtherParameter extends MyAbstractParameter`, the cast would fail, and I will cry.

So I decided to go for `private List<? extends MyAbstractParameter> list;`, but I had to the modify everything so that there is no problem with this `<? ...>`.

So... Is there another way if doing it, while avoiding to modify everything?
I mean.. like doing something in `MyAbstractClass`, without using `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If every element in the list is supposed to be a an instance of T, then the list should be a `List<T>`:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass<T extends MyAbstractParameter> extends Thread {
    private List<T> list;
    public MyAbstractClass(List<T> list) { this.list = list; }
    public List<T> getList() { return list; }

    public void run() {
        for (T e : list) {
             doStuffWithList(e); 
        }
    }
    public abstract void doStuff(T element);
}
```

Comment: I know, but then I want to do this in other class: `List<MyAbstractParameter> otherList = myClass.getList()`, and it doesn't let me, I have to change it to a `List<? extends MyAbstractParameter> otherList`, which is the thing that I want to avoid.

Comment: If you want to return a list where the caller can add any instance of MyAbstractParameter, then you should create a copy of the `List<T>` and return that. Else, you should return a List<T>.

Comment: @Goodwine if you're only getting items from otherList, then `List<? extends MyAbstractParameter>` makes sense. If you're putting items into it with that other class, you might have to make a copy that has the right type parameters using a loop.

Comment: @trutheality It will be read-only, so.. yeah. I just think it looks ugly :P

Comment: If it's read-only, why not return a List<T>? Since T extends MyAbstractParameter, List<T> is a List<? extends MyAbstractParameter>.

Comment: @JBNizet yes, that's what I was going to do, I was just waiting a couple minutes to do this... *accept*